# junk data fix in pyspark or linux command

Tags: linux, pyspark, command, apache-nifi, data-analysis

I have large data set will come from NIFI, then I'll do ETL transformation with pyspark,
unfortunately, one column in middle got split with new line, making extra column and existing records as NULL for same row, So I need to fix with Linux command at Nifi flow or pyspark code while doing ETL transformation

Ex: source.csv

```
1,hi,21.0,final,splitexthere,done,v1,v2,done
2,hi,21.0,final,splitext
here,done,v1,v2,done
3,hi,21.0,final,splitexthere,done,v1,v2,done
4,hi,21.0,final,splitexthere,done,v1,v2,failed
```

expected.csv

```
1,hi,21.0,final,splitexthere,done,v1,v2,done
2,hi,21.0,final,splitexthere,done,v1,v2,done
3,hi,21.0,final,splitexthere,done,v1,v2,done
4,hi,21.0,final,splitexthere,done,v1,v2,failed
```

here are some inputs,
we don't know which column will be split like above splittexhere
id column will be numbers always
and one file has multiple splits with new line

Comment: according to csv rules the value with special symbols (like new line) must be wrapped with `"`. then any csv processor will understand it as a single value

Answer (score 0):

As @daggett highlighted, data must conform to the CSV format specifications to be valid across heterogeneous systems.

Add a `ValidateRecord or ConvertRecord` processor to your NiFi flow to validate CSV to CSV. This will filter out invalid records and valid records from the source data, so basically two forks out of a flowfile and then you can have a separate logic to handle/clean invalid data. Same can be doable in `Spark` as well but in NiFi it is pretty straightforward!

**Note**: While configuring CSVReader schema, make sure that all the fields are **NOT NULL**.

eg. Sample schema for two fields (you have nine fields)

```json
{
"type" : "record",
"namespace" : "com.example.etl",
"name" : "validate_csv_data",
"fields" : [
{ "name" : "col_1", "type" : "string" },
{ "name" : "col_2", "type" : "string" }
]
}
```